# What's wrong with screen range?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TouchMoved and wrong screen range? or Bug in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222013/touchmoved-and-wrong-screen-range-or-bug-in-ios)

I found interesting bug in iOS, but trying to belive that i'm wrong. 
You have to do 2 things:
1) Create single-view template for iOS
2) Write small function in ViewController.m :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}// so u can detect points of your touch
```

---

So if u try to move finger on display from screen's top to bottom (portrait mode) - you get points in range **[-5.5 .. 469]**...
i can't explain this, it happens only on device, in simulator it works fine.