# TouchMoved and wrong screen range? or Bug in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I found interesting bug in iOS, but trying to belive that i'm wrong. You have to do 2 things:

1) Create single-view template for iOS

2) Write small function in ViewController.m :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}// so u can detect points of your touch
```

So if u try to move finger on display from screen's top to bottom (portrait mode) - you get points in range **[-5.5 .. 469]**... i can't explain this, it happens only on device, in simulator it works fine.

**SOME DEBUG INFO:**

with status bar and NO wantsFullScreenLayout range is: [-25.5 .. 449]

with status bar and YES wantsFullScreenLayout range is: [-5.5 .. 469]

without status bar and NO/YES FullScreenLayout the range is: [-5.5 .. 469]

---

with status bar and NO wantsFullScreenLayout view.frame is (0, 20, 320, 460) and view.bounds is (0, 0, 320, 460)

with status bar and YES wantsFullScreenLayout view.frame is (0, 0, 320, 480) and view.bounds is (0, 0, 320, 480)

without status bar and NO/YES FullScreenLayout view.frame is (0, 0, 320, 480) and view.bounds is too (0, 0, 320, 480)

---

Please, help to explain this stuff, it happens only on devices...

Comment: did you take the statusbar into account? Try setting `wantsFullScreenLayout` on your view controller and test again.

Comment: with status bar and NO wantsFullScreenLayout range is: [-25.5 .. 449]

Comment: with status bar and YES wantsFullScreenLayout range is: [-5.5 .. 469]

Comment: without status bar and NO/YES FullScreenLayout the range is: [-5.5 .. 469]

Comment: that's weird. pls add `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.view));` and post the output

Comment: or better replace `self.view` by `[touch view]`

Comment: how can i take NSStringFromCGPoint from [touch view] or self.view?) did u mean self.view.frame.origin? or bounds.origin?

Comment: yes, sorry I meant `self.view.frame.origin`

Comment: without status bar and NO/YES FullScreenLayout frame is (0, 0, 320, 480) and bounds is too (0, 0, 320, 480)

Comment: hmm one last try, log out: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] convertPoint:touch.view.frame.origin fromView:touch.view];`

Comment: with status bar and NO wantsFullScreenLayout frame is (0, 20, 320, 460) and bounds is (0, 0, 320, 460)

Comment: in the `NSLog` statement `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] convertPoint:touch.view.frame.origin fromView:touch.view]));`

Comment: without status bar and NO/YES FullScreenLayout this point is {0, 0}

Comment: Ok, I give up. That's really strange... +1 ^^

Comment: do u test this code on your device?) may be something wrong with my iphone 4...

Comment: No net yet, gotta go soon. If it's not resolved when I come home I'll try it. Are you using a jailbroken device?

Comment: Okay:) nope my device is not jailbroken.

Comment: If you move your finger from screen's top to bottom, won't you open your notification center? And how could you get a negative x position and the y position is almost as big as the screen? Could you paste you code?

Comment: You could test it. Create new single-view project for iOS and add into ViewConroller.m small function that i wrote above. its hyper wierd bug... in simulator it works great, but on device you'll get strange range like [-5,5 .. 469], or with status bar [-25,5 .. 449]

Answer (score 0):

Because the status bar is out of limits of the view. And you gets negative values when you touch on status bar.

Try this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch window]];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

Comment: with status bar and NO wantsFullScreenLayout range is: [-25.5 .. 449]

Comment: with status bar and YES wantsFullScreenLayout range is: [-5.5 .. 469]

Comment: without status bar and NO/YES FullScreenLayout the range is: [-5.5 .. 469]

Comment: @user1229413 Why did you make same comments?

Comment: oh,sorry. i'm newby on stackoverflow. i mean that i tested it with and without status bar. all ranges are wierd

Comment: @user1229413 I did not say try with or without status bar. If you want to detect all your touches on the screen, you should use : CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch **window**]]; not CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch **view**]];

Answer (score 0):

I found this from one of Apple's tutorials on a finger-painting program:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect              bounds = [self bounds];
    UITouch*    touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
    firstTouch = YES;
    // Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)
    location = [touch locationInView:self];
    location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;
}
```

Looks like you need to convert the touch to OpenGL coordinates to get the result you are expecting.  Hope this helps.

Comment: the same bug in GLPaint too, if you write here NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location)) you will get the wrong range - [-5,5 .. 469]

Answer (score 0):

The view of root viewController always acts like portrait mode. You should insert a new view inside of the root one. And this new view will acts correctly, will give right size and coordinates according to Apple says.

for example ;

```
UIView *v = self;
while ([[v superview] superview] != NULL) {
    v = [v superview];
}

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:v];
```

touchPoint will be the correct one.